# Keeping CPU Usage Low for a certain amount of time. c#

Tags: c#, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I have the following code which only allows my application to open after the CPU Usage is below a certain amount of time. But I just need some help adding something that makes sure the usage stays this low for at least 5 seconds so I can avoid any down spikes in CPU Usage.

```
cpuUsage = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
var usage = cpuUsage.NextValue();
do
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    usage = cpuUsage.NextValue();
    Console.WriteLine(usage + "%");
} while (usage > 10.00);

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Documents and Settings\rcgames\Desktop\Game1.exe");
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Did you tried anything to achieve that?

Comment: No... I thought about adding a for loop that slept?

Comment: I'm not a hundred percent sure yet. Which is why im asking for suggestions @venson

Comment: No i meant, whats the Purpose of that Code? What are you Trying to do and Why do you do it like that?

Comment: What happens if it stays below 10% for 5 then you start the game and then boom a CPU spike hits after?  You have achieved nothing with this particular code at that point.  If the game is that CPU intensive I would argue against running it at all on a machine that cant handle it.  I agree with @Venson what exactly is it that you are trying to accomplish with this, I think some more details are needed.

Comment: I just want to check the Usage before the app starts thats all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int secondsWhileLowUsage = 0;     
do {
    cpuUsage = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
    var usage = cpuUsage.NextValue();
    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        usage = cpuUsage.NextValue();
        if (usage > 10.00)
            secondsWhileLowUsage = 0;

        Console.WriteLine(usage + "%");
    } while (usage > 10.00);
    secondsWhileLowUsage ++; 
} while (secondsWhileLowUsage < 5)

Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Documents and Settings\rcgames\Desktop\Game1.exe");
proc.Start();
```